# php mysql number format input value for money

Tags: php, jquery

i use number for my money input value, so when i type the number like

```
15000 then it should be 15,000
55350 became 55,350
```

but when i save that input, why on my database it stored as

```
15.00 and 55.00
```

im using `decimal(18,2)` for this money value

this's my code on the input class

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".mny").number(true); 
     }
```

did i miss something or i should convert the value?
tha

Comment: What is the function decimal() doing? I can't believe I have seen that as a native function.

Comment: Don't store formatted values in the database, store as a PHP float or integer, and only format for display purposes

Comment: @Andreas i mean datatype on mysql

Answer (score 0):

You try like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var withComma = $('#value').val().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    var replaceDot = withComma.replace(/,/g, ".");
    console.log(withComma , replaceDot);
});
```